# Best practice class member initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

When I have a class like:

```
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

export class MyClass {
  protected subject: Subject<string>;
}
```

is it better practice in *TypeScript* to initialize the member `subject` in the constructor like:

```
export class MyClass {
  protected subject: Subject<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.subject = new Subject<string>();
  }
}
```

or inline in the class body like:

```
export class MyClass {
  protected subject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
}
```

**NOTE**

Inline initialization obviously only works with imported classes like `Subject` in this case, not with injected classes, which would only be present in the constructor.

**EDIT**

The [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) does not contain this part.

Comment: Don't think there is any best practice, I prefer inline when the inital value does not depend on ctor params..

Comment: Yes, me too. Smaller classes. But it's feels sometimes inconsistent, when mixing both technics. And switched between both depending of the constructor parameter list, is also not that smooth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing variables inline during declaration vs in the constructor in Angular with TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494083/initializing-variables-inline-during-declaration-vs-in-the-constructor-in-angula)

Comment: They're the same. I usually initialize everything inline, except when there's more logic behind it. So I probably won't to `protected subject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.getDefaultValueOfSubject());`

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter. Both code snippets will be transpiled exactly to the same code which is

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.subject = new Subject();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting aspect. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @scipper [you can verify it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkCeBhVDOAbwCg44woIZgFaATONAVwCMArOmALjgGV2XegB40MKAEsAdgHMAfHAC8cacADuAodzESZCgBQBKANykAvqVKhIsRIUy4C6TGQpUa3YE1adufQT9RcSk5eTNyRAhpEJZ6aGMSSIoYAAtJNAA6X2F4FTVNQNzdUMNTSMtzIA) (if you ever have similar questions)

Comment: @Maryannah yes, is just did it :)