# Error: "Can't create a Google Chart without data!" when data loaded inside an aync Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angular

I am really struggling to get this working.
When I get data from an Angular Service inside a component, I get console error that Google Chart can't be loaded without data. When I declare data outside of Service.subscribe the chart works fine. I think google charts is being called even before the service returns, so how can I make it wait for it?
Please take a look at code snippet below. Appreciate any help or pointers.

Here is the library I'm using https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts

#### app.module.ts

```
import { GoogleChartsModule } from 'angular-google-charts';
...
  ],
  imports: [
...
        GoogleChartsModule
  ],
...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### component.html

```html
<google-chart #chart
[title]="title"
[type]="type"
[data]="chartData"
[options]="options"
[width]="width"
[height]="height">
</google-chart>
```

#### component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MilestoneService } from 'src/app/milestone.service';
import { Milestone } from 'src/app/milestone';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-timeline',
    templateUrl: './timeline.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timeline.component.css']
})
export class TimelineComponent implements OnInit {

title: string
type: string
chartData: Array<Array<any>>
options: {}
width: number
height: number

constructor(
private milestoneService: MilestoneService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.title = 'Some title'
this.type = 'Timeline'
this.width = 550
this.height = 400
this.options = {}

// IF I UNCOMMENT THIS, IT WORKS!
// this.chartData = [
//  ['program 1', 'milestone 1', new Date('2019-10-10'), new Date('2019-11-11')],
//  ['program 2', 'milestone 2', new Date('2019-11-14'), new Date('2019-12-10')],
// ]

this.milestoneService.getMilestonesTimeline().subscribe((data: Milestone[]) => {
// WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?
this.chartData = data.map(d => [d.program, d.title, new Date(d.start), new Date(d.end)])
})
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Ludwig's answer. But adding structural directives ***ngIf** will effect on dom performance. Simply you can intialize **chartData** with empty two dimensional array like below.

**app-component.html**

```
<google-chart [type]="myType" [data]="myData" ></google-chart>
```

**app-component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    myData:any = [[]] ;
    myType = 'PieChart';

    ngOnInit() {

      // getting sample data from backend
     // myData will be myData = [['Wakanda',1200],['Brooklyn',10000]]


     this.http.get('http://localhost:1234/getChartData').subscribe(data => {
      this.myData = data;
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I have a question though - initializing the property should be done inside constructor or where it's declared like you have done so?

Comment: Intializing outside constructor is not at all a problem...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494083/initializing-variables-inline-during-declaration-vs-in-the-constructor-in-angula

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. The chart is executed before the data is available.
Add *ngIf="chartData" to your google-chart tag:

```
<google-chart #chart *ngIf="chartData"
 ...
</google-chart>
```

This prevents the google chart to be executed as long as chartData equals undefined.

Comment: Thank you Ludwig - your solutions works as well, however marking the other one as I wanted to address this inside of component controller because of cleaner code.